# How image size is calculated?

Tags: image, binary, image-segmentation

I am created 1×1 bitmap image with the  color depth 1 bit color and i am expected image size will to be 0.125 bytes but the image size is displayed in my windows 10 and my mobile phone 66 bytes.

Comment: How do you expect a size of less than a byte?

Comment: 1 px having 1 bit color depth so 1 bit equals to 0.125 byte then 1px*1px*0.125

Comment: Yes, but do you know any file system that stores less than a byte? You can optimize and fit some of your zero point something pixels in less bytes in memory, but a file system may even use 512, 2048, or even 4096 bytes as smallest allocation unit.  Put "file system block size" in your favorite search engine.